# Проблема подлючении компонента при сборке vue-cli?

Tags: vue.js

Не могу подключить компонент при создания проекта

```js
//подключаю компонет к главному экземпляру 

<template>
    <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" v-bind:style="width"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>


  export default {
    props: {
    max: Number,
    val: Number
  },
  computed: {
    width() {
      let w=this.val/this.max*100;
      return {
        width: w+'1%'
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  div {color: red;}
</style>
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
  <div id="app">
    <div>Sum: {{sum}}</div>
    <app v-bind:val="sum" v-bind:max="maxNumbers*5"></app>
    <hr>
    <app v-bind:val="numbers.length" v-bind:max="maxNumbers"></app>
    
    <button @click="AddNumber()" >Add number</button>
    <li v-for="number in numbers">
      {{ number }}
    </li>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  import Progress from './Progress.vue';

  export default {
    data() {
    return {
      numbers:[],
      maxNumbers: 3
    }
  },
  computed: {
    sum() {
      let sum=0;
      for (let i=0; i<this.numbers.length; i++) {
        sum+=this.numbers[i];
      }
      return sum;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    AddNumber() {
      this.numbers.push(Math.random());
    }
  },
  components: {
    AppProgress: Progress
  }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  div {color: red;}
</style>
```

Comment: _«Не могу»_ - это очень неинформативно. Какие трудности? Выводится ошибка? Какая именно? Она выводится при сборке проекта, или в консоли браузера при открытии страницы с веб-приложением?

Comment: [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <app> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>

Comment: Понятно. Суть в том что компонент App не зарегистрирован. Пожалуйста, добавь в вопрос эту ошибку, и содержимое главного js-файла (энтрипоинта сборщика, обычно `src/main.js` или `src/index.js`). В том файле главный экземпляр Vue инстанцируется, и в нем же должен импортироваться App.

Comment: странно я тут указал components: {
    AppProgress: Progress
  }
а что не так? как исправить более детально хочу увидеть

Comment: App !== Progress. Как исправить - для начала, добавить в вопрос информацию, необходимую для ответа.

Comment: все кинул, ошыбку тоже написал если не знаешь почему ты сюда пишешь ???

Comment: Я писал сюда затем чтобы: **1.** повысить низкое качество твоего вопроса; **2.** дать ответ на него. Но после фразы _"если не знаешь почему ты сюда пишешь"_ - намерение отвечать пропало. Удачи.

Comment: отвечай не много а качество

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замени `app` на `app-progress`:

```
<app-progress v-bind:val="sum" v-bind:max="maxNumbers*5"></app-progress>
<app-progress v-bind:val="numbers.length" v-bind:max="maxNumbers"></app-progress>
```

Ты компоненту имя дал `AppProgress`, а используешь `<app />`